# How was the Weierstrass function created?

Tags: calculus

If I understand it, the Weierstrauss function was the first of its kind that is continuous everywhere by differentiable nowhere.  The function is generated as a series that converges, but whose derivative does not.  How did they do that?  At the time, it wasn't known that continuity doesn't imply differentiability.  So Weierstrauss had to have generated two series, one of which happens to be the derivative of the other (using classifical definitions of the derivative) but that doesn't converge...I'm just looking to better understand the insight that lead to its discovery.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I believe you that "it wasn't known that continuity doesn't imply differentiability". Are you sure people weren't aware of the absolute value function?

Comment: BTW the name is written Weierstrass (without u) or Weierstraß

Comment: @0x539 One of my pet hates!

Comment: At the time functions that they studied that were continuous were differentiable almost everywhere.  The absolute value function is such a function.  However, the Weierstrass (sp!) function is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

Comment: How did you get that Germanic ss character in LaTeX?

Comment: @MarkFischler if you mean the "ß": it's not LaTeX, it's on my Keyboard. But you can get it in LaTeX with `\ss`